# Sum increment inside public static int not working

Tags: java, increment

I was working on project Euler problem 14: https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

I tried out a test case: Here's my code:

```
public class problem015 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println(Collatz(13));

}

public static int Collatz (int n){
    int sum = 1;
    if (n == 1) 
        return sum;
    if (n%2 == 0) {
        sum ++;
        return Collatz(n/2);            
    }
    if (n%2 == 1){
        sum ++;
        return Collatz(1 + (3*n));
    }
    else return 0;
}

}
```

Theoretically, this should return a value of 10 when I tested it with the number 13 (10 numbers in the Collatz sequence, see link). However, it just returns the initial value I assign to the integer 'sum'.

Any ideas why?

EDIT: I think it's because every time it loops back to the Collatz function, it resets the value of 'sum'. If this is the case, how do I declare the value of 'sum' independently?

Comment: To answer your edit simply pass sum as an argument in your function call.

Comment: `sum` is a local variable in `Collatz()` ,so a new `sum` is created with each call and initialized to 1.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `sum`.

```
public static int Collatz (int n){

    if (n == 1) 
        return 1;
    if (n%2 == 0) {
        return 1 + Collatz(n/2);            
    }else{
        return 1 + Collatz(1 + (3*n));
    }

}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks! Very stupid of me not to think of doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the recursive call, you never pass in "sum", so it does not get incremented.

You'll want your base case (n==1) to return 1.  Each of the other cases should return 1 + Collatz(nextNumberInTheSequence).

Comment: Even if he did it gets overwritten by `int sum = 1`

Comment: @TangledUpInBlue I don't quite understand how to fix that. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @redFIVE yup, I realised that (and edited to that effect.). How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to be told how to pass parameters to methods?

Comment: @redFIVE Will search that up now. I didn't know how to pass parameters to methods.

Comment: Then why are you on project euler? You are literally already doing it twice in your code. Is this even your code?

Comment: @redFIVE This is my code. If that's the case, then what I meant was not knowing how to use a variable that wasn't local inside the method. Look, I'm a relatively young coder seeking help and willing to learn. :)

Comment: You should probably take some time learning the basics before tackling hard computational questions which you have cause you to come here for java basic help